# How to use Body parameter In an API Post request using Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, api, http, bad-request

I wanted to know how to add a body to an api request using typescript. Ive done this request on postman and i got the response, however i dont know how to do it using typescript. I keep getting a "BAD REQUEST". I check the api documentation from the host and they showed me how to do it:

```
Request Format
POST https://api.channeladvisor.com/oauth2/token

Authorization: Basic [application id:shared secret]
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Body: grant_type = refresh_token &
      refresh_token = [refresh token]
```

I have the refresh token and the authorization details with me. So i tried doing this in typescript:

```
this.http.post('https://api.channeladvisor.com/oauth2/token',                    
  {body:{
    grant_type:"refresh_token",
    refresh_token:this.refresh_token
  }},

  {headers:{
    'Authorization':this.token
    }})
.subscribe((response)=>{
    this.new_token=response;
    console.log("This is the new token")
      console.log(this.new_token)
  })
}
```

But when i run it i get a bad request error. I assume it has something do with with the syntax.

Comment: The second argument to the post method is the body, you're including the key body in the body itself. Also you need to look up how to send it url encoded not serialised as JSON, which is the default.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request

Comment: HTTP Example Request
POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: api.channeladvisor.com
Authorization: Basic MTIzNDU6YWJjZGU=
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache

grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=acCD58Efghijk1L7mn-OPq0rTqOb5oRsTUvwxyZabcD

Comment: theyve given this way as well but where should i include this part: grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=acCD58Efghijk1L7mn-OPq0rTqOb5oRsTUvwxyZabcD –

Answer (score 0):

You have the following body requirement:

```
  grant_type = refresh_token &
  refresh_token = [refresh token]
```

With content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

## Error

Your code:

```
this.http.post('https://api.channeladvisor.com/oauth2/token',                    
  {body:{
    grant_type:"refresh_token",
    refresh_token:this.refresh_token
  }},
```

is going to send `content-type` `application/json` with json formatted body.

## Fix

Fixed code:

```
this.http.post('https://api.channeladvisor.com/oauth2/token',                    
  {body:`
    grant_type = refresh_token &
    refresh_token = ${something}
  `},
  {headers:{
    'Authorization':this.token,
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }})
```

Comment: I tried it and im still getting 404 bad request. Are there any other ways i can include the body?